# Get Regexp::Common URI working

Tags: regex, perl, url

im using pQuery to get all TD cells from a table checking if it contains a valid URL.
pQuery is working fine giving me the content of all TD cells.
But my Regexp::Common check which i have from stackoverflow doesnt work.

Heres my code:

```
use Regexp::Common qw/URI/;
use pQuery;

pQuery( $url)
->find( "table")
->find( "tr")
->find( "td")
->each( sub {
  my $domain = pQuery( $_)->text;
  if( $domain =~ /$RE{URI}{HTTP}/) {
    print "OK\n";
  }
});
```

The variable $domain contains the content of a TD cell, some of them have domains in it.
They all look like "hello-world.com" or "www.test.net".
The text "OK" doesnt get printed. Whats wrong here?
Is it because the domains are in the format above? No HTTP, no WWW. I want a simple check if the text is a valid URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content is not a HTTP URI, so using `$RE{URI}{HTTP}` will not match, it looks like your trying to match domain names, for that you want to use `use Regexp::Common qw/net/;` and `$RE{net}{domain}{-nospace}`.

Comment: Ok i think this is the solution. But there is a cell which contains all TLD's of the current domain in the cell before. So for some reason this regexp also returns TRUE for the TLD's like "com net" or "biz". I just added this to my regexp check "$domain =~ m/\./", so its working now. Thanks. Maybe there is a regexp to also check for full domain name including the point.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the RE requires the `http://` on the front. You can fudge it in your test:

```
  if( "http://$domain" =~ /$RE{URI}{HTTP}/) {
```

Comment: A good solution. But i do not know if really all domains are without the "http://" prefix. So i would need to check for it first before i do the regexp. But thats a solution. Thanks

Comment: You could do two regexp checks, I guess; one with the prefix, one without.

Answer (score 0):

"hell-world.com" and the rest don't  start with "http://", which is what the regex expects
check the documentation for Regexp::Common (and it's related modules), or have a look at the regex itself:

```
print $RE{URI}{HTTP};
```

Paul